# Override Domain CRUD methods with Domain.load() proxies

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I try to override the delete() method of some of my domains.
I've used the following code in my Bootstrap.init() method :

```
    grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { clazz ->

        clazz.newInstance() // method to trigger metaclass wiring

        def gormDelete = clazz.metaClass.getMetaMethod('delete')
        clazz.metaClass.delete = { ->
            println "OVERRIDED DELETE() VERSION"
            // Code
            return gormDelete.invoke(delegate)
        }
    }
```

This solution works when I have a "real" domain class (with new Domain() or Domain.get(), ...) but it doesn't works when using the Domain.load() method.

Domain.load(1).delete() uses the standard GORM delete() method and not my overrided version.

The class returned by the load() method is a proxy (Domain_$$_javassist_XX), which explains why it doesn't use my overrided methods.

What can I do to override the domain CRUD methods AND the associated domain proxies?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The [ref-doc](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html) states clearly:

> load
> Purpose
>
> Returns a proxy instance of the domain class for the given identifier.

if you still want to use `load()` instead of `get()`, you gonna have to override the `load()` as well

Comment: Is it possible to override the proxy's delete() method, to match the one used on the domain ?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to override them? Wouldn't it be better (more abstract) to add a remove() method to your domains like that:

```
void remove() {
    delete()
}
```

and change the implementation where needed

Comment: I've already done that (the overrided delete() method calls the remove() method). But I don't want the devs to use the standard "delete()", and in case of cascade deletes, I want grails to call my overrided version because it adds some delete logics